# Need help in understanding Scenario and writing SQL

Tags: sql

Thank you very much. I need to add a particular functionality to  all records and the record counts. i have pasted it here-

- The requirement for this scenario as given to me is just below and its in BOLD and Italics.
  I am somewhat confused with the scenario on how to write the SQL query that gives us "%"
  (percentage)-

***Take the latest scripts for all clients and add percentages to all record counts per the instructions at the top of these scripts (when the % is at least 1%).

Be sure to use the total record count at the time of each test to get your %’s.  We need these %’s for all time periods that are latest.***

I have to ensure that we have these %’s so we can see meaningful trends in latest SQL scripts.  Just looking at records counts in these scripts is not nearly as useful"

My Understanding- What i get is I need to add % for record counts ,but its confusing that
**(when the % is at least 1%)**.  So,if any field is BLANK/NULL or empty =-how would i handle it?

Need your help in writing the SQL query to add % by taking the condition of BLANK/NULL or empty

Code Sample-

Give % of total records if greater than 0%, and put the date next to the count for each query

Presently, SQL query to get total count

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM Table A;
```

I am new to SQL.So,please correct me if i understood it wrongly.

When  Count(1) is used,it filters all NULL values

Also,i have seen

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table A;
```

COUNT(*) gives total record count including null values.

Now,next SQL queries are executed for each field-

```
--Count members 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B_id)
FROM enrollment;
```

Hence,now i have given to write an SQL query to calculate %  and to include the "% " for each record count.
I suppose it will total count of the Table divide by each column count.

**Hi,
Thank you very much for formatting my query.I am gradually trying to learn formatting.
I have not received any suggestions/answers for my query and i have been waiting for your inputs on how to get SQL queries correctly.
I am sorry for making it bold,i just wanted to highlight.
Requesting again for helping
*****strong text***

Thanks Hamlin.

" We require that all values from record counts should have to display the percentage value also. 
Let me explain with above example -
 1) Initially lets take a table A and a partcular colum called "B_id"  .
 So lets get the record count without NULLs for which I used COUNT(1). There are values which are NULL for B_id.

So,for this field,Total = 100

2)Next,we get the total record count of the Table(So,here we get everything)= 150

Now,if we see the above requirement-

"So,I hope i explained better now. Finally,I need percentages of  all record counts for each Column like B_id,SSN,etc

**Also,must take care of a scenario when it comes 0.76% ->Then I need to round off it to 1%
So,SQL query should calculate %

(when the % is at least 1%).**

So i need a

Comment: I understand, you need to modify an already existing script. Why don't you post or at least outline it here?

Comment: Hi,   I have code sample as an example.

Comment: **Hi,   I have given above code sample as an example. First Query gives me record of a particular field by removing all Blanks. The,I do a query on the entire table which gives total row count irrespective of NULLs.So,please help me with a query which gives % of values present **

Comment: @Rohit, I have tried, but can't make sense of the question. It would help me if you can try to present the question in a more understandable form. Pretend I'm a programmer that you are assigning a task to, and you only have one chance to give me all of the information.

Comment: Thanks Hamlin. " We require that all values from record counts should have to display the percentage value also.

Answer (score 0):

I see why people are not responding. The question is unclear, and based on what I got out of reading it two or three times, the requirement is not all the clear either. At any rate, I can try to help with a few issues:

a) There is most likely no difference between `count(*)` and `count(1)` in your example, unless you are using a non-standard database. That is:

```
select count(1) from tableA
```

and

```
select count(*) from tableA
```

return the exact same answer. Both ignore non-existent records. Try it and you will see.

b) To get percentages, you are correct that you have to run two queries. Here is a possible method. First, get the total number, with something like this:

```
select count(*) from TableA
```

Then, get the count per item, and divide that by the total.

```
select item, count(*) from TableA group by item
```

Combine those into a larger select statement, maybe like this:

```
select x.item, round (x.nbr / (select count(*) from TableA), 2) * 100 as Pct
from (
  select item, count(*) as nbr
  from TableA 
  group by item
  ) x
```

c) Which SQL are you using? Syntax varies enough to make it worth your time to tell us.

d) Your concern for nulls is unnecessary. Generally, if a record does not exist, SQL statements will ignore it. I could be missing your point, but I don't think that will be one of your top concerns. On the other hand, null values are special in SQL, as they are not zero and nulls don't equal anything. Null does not even equal null. If there is a problem with null values in the code above, you might have to do this:

```
select x.item, round (x.nbr / (select count(*) from TableA), 2) * 100 as Pct
from (
  select item, count(*) as nbr
  from TableA 
  where item is not null
  group by item
  ) x
```

Hope this helps. It might not be the answer you are looking for, but I think it might get you started on the way to formulating the question better.